# Why is thread.sleep crashing my JavaFX app?

Tags: java, javafx, thread-sleep

I have a for loop that iterates through all the players in my game. Before the next iteration, I want to allow the current player 3 minutes to make a selection(which is the canvas mouseclick event).  Everything I have tried crashes my app with no errors.  I've been at this for hours with no clue of what's going on.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    startGame.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {

                gameStatus = "Started";
                players.add(new Player(0, "Amrit"));
                players.add(new Player(1, "Tyler"));
                players.add(new Player(2, "Scott"));
                players.add(new Player(3, "Ryker"));

                //Select first two settlements with one road extending from each
                for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++) {

                    for (int p = 0; p < players.size(); p++) {

                        phase = "Pick Settlements";
                        playerTurn = p;

                        //Loop through all tiles
                        for (int t = 0; t < tiles.length; t++) {

                            //Loop through the vertices of the current tile
                            for (int v = 0; v < tiles[t].vertices.length; v++) {

                                drawCircle(gc, new Point(tiles[t].vertices[v].x, tiles[t].vertices[v].y), (int) (windowHeight * .05), true, true, "rgba(255, 238, 144, .3)", 0);

                            }

                        }

                        gc.setFill(Color.web("0xFFEB8A"));
                        gc.strokeText(players.get(p).name + ", please place your first settlement!", windowHeight * .95, windowWidth * .85);
                        selected = false;
                        canvas.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                            // @Override
                            @Override
                            public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
                                if (!pointClicked().equals(0)) {
                                    players.get(playerTurn).settlementsAvail--;
                                    selected = true;
                                }
                            }

                        });

                        try 
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 3);
                        } 
                        catch(InterruptedException er)
                        {
                             // this part is executed when an exception (in this example InterruptedException) occurs
                        }
                    }

                }

                gameStatus = "Ended";

            }

        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to sleep in the actual click handler? That will probably lock down your entire program (or at least the user interaction) for quite some time. And please post the actual exception and the error message.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about this but the startGame handler is separate from the click handler(canvas) i want to allow time for.  the canvas click handler is a little further down the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are sleeping on the FX application thread. This will freeze your entire GUI making it unable to process user inputs. Instead use either a `TimeLine`:

```
Timeline timer = new Timeline(            
      new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(60 * 3), event -> finishedSleeping())
);
timer.play();
```

or a javafx `Task`:

```
Task<Void> timer = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
       try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 3);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
       return null;    
    }
};
timer.setOnSucceeded(event -> finishedSleeping());
new Thread(timer).start();
```

In this examples sleeping happens on a thread different from the FX application thread. `finishedSleeping()` will be called on the FX application thread once the 3 minutes are over.

Comment: With the first method, the app no longer crashes but the timer doesn't do anything.  Everything continues as normal.  As for the second method, I get errors.  Specifically: type Task does not take parameters and method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 You have to import  `javafx.concurrent.Task` for the second approach. Both methods should work fine. From the point on where you call `timer.play()/new Thread(timer).start();` it should take about 3 minutes until `finishedSleeping()` in the example is called. Of course, instead of the looping you have currently in the code you need to implement an event handler (`event -> finishedSleeping()`) that handles reaching the end of the 3 minutes waiting.

Comment: Ok so with the first method I did originally import the wrong Task class.  But neither of the methods above do anything.  Everything is executed right away.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 When you insert the code  of one of the two methods, everything after `timer.play();/new Thread(timer).start();` will be executed right away, because sleeping happens on another thread. That is why you have to abandon the two enclosing for-loops. The code which you replace `finishedSleeping()` with, will be executed after 3*60 secs.